# I am sending form data which contains zip file as well as few other parameter from angular 2, but In Java back end I finding difficulties to consume

Tags: java, angular, rest, jax-rs, jax-ws

the error which I am getting is 415 Unsupported media type.

I am sending form data with zip file as well as few other parameters.
In angular2 I am setting content type as multipart/form-data.

In Java backend also consume as multipart/form data.
I am using javax.ws.rs api.
The methods which I have tried.
Using @FormParam didn't work
Using FileInputStream didn't work

I can't use FormDataParam because I am not using jersey. I need alternate of FormDataParam in jax-ws-rs.

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation are you using? Each implementation has their own MultiPart support. Just read the documentation. The `@FormDataParam` for Jersey handles MultiPart, so that's what you want, as that's the type of request that is being sent.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I am not using Jersey framework, I am using core jax-rs api.

Comment: Core JAX-RS APIs have no support for Multipart. You need to use an implementation's APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Try with   *@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)*

Answer (score 0):

In Backend, you receive a MultipartFile. In Java Spring it has to look looks as follows:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> postData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("agencyId") Long agencyId) {
 // your Business-Code here
}
```

On Frontend-Side, you can push the file and the other parameter as Formdata as following. The example uses a String-Value and a zip-file named 'file', both in FormData:

```
// Popup for fileupload
let inputElement = document.createElement("input");
inputElement.type = 'file';
inputElement.accept = 'zip';

// get file, chosen by user in popup
let files = fileChosenEvent.target as HTMLInputElement;

// create FormData
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('agencyId', agencyId.toString())
formData.append('file', new Blob([files.files[0]], { type: application/octet-stream" }), file.name);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If nothing helps, you can also use the underlying Request directly. In Java Spring, simply use HttpServletRequest in your controller-method: public ResponseEntity<?> someMethod(HttpServletRequest request) { .. } ... with this, you prevent parsing-errors but you have to map yourself